# The nuance of "already" in the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

[The Source](http://www.newyorker.com/arts/critics/cinema/2013/10/14/131014crci_cinema_lane?currentPage=all)

> They then drive away and, in the movie’s weakest scene, explain to
>   each other how dangerous the world has become. Thanks, guys. Our
>   nerves **already** gave us the bad news.

Does this "already" imply that the scene shot from within the house had already given us the idea of how dangerous the world has become?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does; **already** has the fairly simple meaning of "happened in the past", and **Our nerves** indicates that something (a previous scene) had made us nervous and thus communicated the message of danger.

Comment: +1 The author specifically indicates that way in which the  previous scene is cut makes us nervous.